# fill_in hidden_field with capybara error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am trying to set the value for a hidden_field but I am getting an error:

in pry

```
find("#element_id", visible: false)
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="input">
```

now trying to set it returns an error

```
find("#element_id", visible: false).set true
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
(Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301326     (093c7e07b4a916b690e784b0374c7f618f1ea4be),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.1 x86_64)
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
```

Any ideas would be great!  I also tried using xpath but to no avail.  Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 3):

using this worked..

```
page.execute_script(“$(‘#hidden_input_id’).val(‘value’)”)
```

Found the answer here:

https://devmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2013/09/20/capybara-cheat-sheet/